# How to send the disabled multiple select value to server

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, select, struts

I have the following select which is multiselect

```
<html:select property="select1" styleId="select1" style="width:330px;" size="6" multiple="true" disabled="true">
    <html:optionsCollection property="wo" value="id" label="idAndRef"    />                                         
</html:select>

<html:hidden property="select1"  styleId="select1"/>
```

I have a hidden property since the select is disabled.

and i am able to set the values like the following since the select is `disabled`

```
var select = document.getElementById('select1');
if (select.disabled) {
    // If disabled, do this 
    var allOptions = new Array;
    $('#styleId option').each(function(){
        allOptions.push($(this).val());
    });

    var arrayLength = allOptions.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        select.options[i].value = allOptions[i]
        select.options[i].selected = true;
    }

    //document.forms[0].styleId.value=allOptions; 
    return true;
}
```

but when i debug and checked in server i get the following as a the value for  `select1`

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@42205593]
```

i am not getting as why the above one comes as value instead of the string array.

```
private String[] select1 = new String[] {}; //is how it is declared in struts form.
```

Comment: because a hidden field can only contain a single value, as text. It cannot store an array. You'd have to put the values in the hidden field as comma-separated, perhaps, and then parse that string manually on the server-side.

Comment: @ADyson oh thanks for pointing that and how do i overcome this?

Comment: I've already suggested a way...read it again. I can't actually see how you are storing the values in the hidden field right now? It's not clear from the code. Also it looks like maybe you gave both your select and your hidden field the same ID and name (I don't know this struts syntax)? You can't have two elements with the same ID - JavaScript will not be able to find the second one, and if you give both the same name, then when you submit values to the server and the select is _not_ disabled, there's potential confusion about which field's value gets submitted using that name.